# How to check if all <select> are selected

Tags: javascript, html

I have three select elements in my HTML code. I want to receive a `alert` when all three are selected.

```
<select id="day" name="day" onchange="report()">
    <option disabled selected>Day</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
<select id="month" name="month" onchange="report()">
    <option disabled selected>Month</option>
    <option value="1">January</option>
    <option value="2">February</option>
</select>
<select id="year" name="year" onchange="report()">
    <option disabled selected>Year</option>
    <option value="2005">2005</option>
    <option value="2004">2004</option>
</select>
```

I made it so that it works, but for example when you select `day` and `month` and change the value of `month` again, my code already alerts me but the year was not selected yet. That's because I used a global variable that increments. I'm looking for a better solution.

```
var x = 0;
function report() {
    x += 1;
    if (x == 3) {
        alert('All three are selected');
    }
}
```

Comment: Your selects have only one option. And you don't "check" the select elements. Don't you need to use checkboxes instead?

Comment: @Ram No they have more then one option but I shorted my code for you guys :>

Comment: Your question needs clarfication then. Do you want to check if the selected options have the same values? In this case "1"?

Comment: Is there a default option with empty value, and you want to check that they've selected a non-default value in all?

Comment: @Ram Basically there are three <select> fields where the user can enter their date of birth. For example, 01.January.2005 or 09.March.1999. I want an <alert> to be output after the user enters a complete date so that all <select> are selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The smart way to solve it is not by checking the value of every Select. Simply count the amounts of `<option>` with the `disabled` attribute that is currently selected by using `document.querySelectorAll('option[disabled]:checked').length`. Then you you make an simply if comparison with `variableName === 0` or simply `!variableName`:

```js
const SELECTS = document.querySelectorAll('select');

SELECTS.forEach(select => {
  select.addEventListener('change', function() {
    let disabledOptionsLength = document.querySelectorAll('option[disabled]:checked').length;
    if (!disabledOptionsLength) {
      console.log('all selected');
    } else {
      console.log(`${disabledOptionsLength} options have not been selected`);
    }
  })
 })
```

```html
<select id="day" name="day">
    <option disabled selected>Day</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
<select id="month" name="month">
    <option disabled selected>Month</option>
    <option value="1">January</option>
    <option value="2">February</option>
</select>
<select id="year" name="year">
    <option disabled selected>Year</option>
    <option value="2005">2005</option>
    <option value="2004">2004</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks @tacoshy, it works really well! I have a general question. Normally I have to call a JavaScript function in HTML like for example `<select id="day" name="day" onchange="report()">`, but that's not the case with your code. Why is that?

Comment: onchangr is a method you rarely use in modern JS as updates then have to be done in 2 places. The HTML and the JS file. I used an `addEventListener` on all Selects that listen to change events within the JS itself.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your code is that you will trigger the alert if you change any single select 3 times, which isn't the desired outcome. In the answer below instantiate variables to false for day, month and year.  When each one is changed, they get set to true. When all are true, your alert gets triggered.

```js
let rday = false;
let rmonth = false;
let ryear = false;

function reportDay() {
  rday = true
  if (rday && rmonth && ryear) {
    alert('All three are selected');
  }
}

function reportMonth() {
  rmonth = true
  if (rday && rmonth && ryear) {
    alert('All three are selected');
  }
}

function reportYear() {
  ryear = true
  if (rday && rmonth && ryear) {
    alert('All three are selected');
  }
}
```

```html
<select onchange="reportDay()">
  <option disabled selected>Day</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
<select onchange="reportMonth()">
  <option disabled selected>Month</option>
  <option value="1">Januar</option>
  <option value="2">Februar</option>
</select>
<select onchange="reportYear()">
  <option disabled selected>Year</option>
  <option value="2005">2005</option>
  <option value="2004">2004</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need 3 functions for this as just one will do. Within the `report()` function, use the select element id's to check the state of each select, to see if it has been selected to something other than the default initial value. For example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My HTML Page</title>
    <script>
        var reported = false; // so the alert only occurs once
        function report() {
          var day = document.getElementById("day").value;
          var month = document.getElementById("month").value;
          var year = document.getElementById("year").value;
          if (day != "Day" && month != "Month" && year != "Year" && reported == false) {
            alert("You were born on " + day + "/" + month + "/" + year);
            reported = true;
          }
        }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <select id="day" name="day" onchange="report()">
      <option disabled selected>Day</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>
    <select id="month" name="month" onchange="report()">
      <option disabled selected>Month</option>
      <option value="1">January</option>
      <option value="2">February</option>
    </select>
    <select id="year" name="year" onchange="report()">
      <option disabled selected>Year</option>
      <option value="2005">2005</option>
      <option value="2004">2004</option>
    </select>
  </body>
</html>
```